# Larvel5.5 how to change the method findOrFail key name?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

my MySQL table articles primary key name is `a_id`, but when I use `findOrFail` method this function search to database key name is `id`, so how can I change the key from `id` to `a_id`?

```
public function edit($a_id)
{
    $articleData = Article::findOrFail('a_id',$a_id);
    return view('Admin.articleEdit')->with('articleData',$articleData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would set the primary key on your Eloquent Model.

```
class Article extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'a_id';
```

See the Primary key paragraph here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#defining-models

Answer (score 0):

findOrFail() is a method that specifically looks for an identifier field called "id", the standard naming convention to name a primary key.  Unless you are trying to mask the column name of your id field, I suggest you just go with id.

To use findOrFail, you will need to update your table to have an id field named "id" or define your primary key in the model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'admin_id';
```

The other option is to use firstOrFail() like this:

```
Article::where('a_id','=',$a_id)->firstOrFail();
```

Here is an [article](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) on Eloquent methods that will help you learn more about findOrFail or FirstOrFail()